# How to create docker image for dotnet app?

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, hyperledger-indy

I have a dotnet project that work when i do dotnet run, i am trying to containerize that dotnet project.
For that i have create the Dockerfile as below:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1

COPY bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/publish/ App/
WORKDIR /App

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["dotnet", "MediatorAgent.dll"]
```

Before creating the docker image i did run `dotnet publish -c Release`. Now when i try to run this docker image, i am getting the below error

> Unhandled exception. System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'indy' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: libindy: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I am following the instruction for [Containerize a .NET Core app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/docker/build-container?tabs=linux) for creating docker image.

Answer (score 2):

> How to create docker image for dotnet app?

Well, you did it.

What is likely to have gone wrong is that the DLL refered to as `indy` is not copied to the App folder.

Since you are copying the data, please verify it's included in the original build at  `bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/publish`

Comment: I did add this libindy.so file to bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/publish folder, but still getting the same issue. Earlier dotnet run wasnt working so i did sudo apt-get install -y libindy, this added libindy.so in /usr/lib so i copied that libindy.so to publish folder

Comment: Ok, so - you are able to run it locally on your machine I suppose. Compare the output debug folder with the output publish folder and see if there is a file in the debug folder, but not in the publish folder. In 99% of all cases this is due to the missing of the specific file. How did you referenced the file in your project?

Answer (score 0):

make sure `bin/Release/` directory available in the same directory where your Dockerfile exist.

You can specify the project .csproj or .sln to build.

You can have a look on below dockerfile, hope that will help you.

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build AS builder
WORKDIR /source

COPY projectname.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet build projectname.csproj -c Release -o /app/build

COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "projectname.dll"]
```